# How to get input from the user with a java program running in the background? (SetWindowsHookEx)

Tags: java, input, background, keylogger

Is there any way to get input from the user when the program is running in the background?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to make a key logger using Java?

Comment: Yes, because I have nothing to do, so I decided to make a Keylogger

Comment: 1) Java isn't a good language for this, and so you'll 2) have to use JNI, JNA or some other programming language if you want to write code that lets you spy on your wife or girlfriend.

Comment: :p It's for my friend, and i'll try using python.

Comment: Yeah, it's OK to help **them** spy on their wife or girlfriend. That makes it OK. Why didn't you tell us this from the beginning? Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pop up a GUI asking for input.  The following prompts the user for a string:

```
String myString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input some string");
```

You will need to import `javax.swing.JOptionPane`

The javadoc is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html.  Note that `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` will return `null` if the user cancels out of the dialog.

Comment: Um,... that's not what he's looking for. He's trying to write spyware, a keylogger.

Comment: Oh. I assumed that by 'background' he meant an application that didn't have a graphical component or terminal to output to.  I started my post before he mentioned it was supposed to be a keylogger.